# Question about adding a new STATE in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have built a web page with flex 4, I want the user to click the LOGIN button and have a popup window appear to enter login info.  I have set this up so that there is a login state with the login box in it, the problem is that everything else disappears (menu bar, etc). Obviously this is because not all of my objects are viewable "IN ALL STATES", but do I really have to go back and change every little thing to show up in all states for this to happen, or is there a way for the login popup to just overlay on top of everything else temporarily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `PopUpManager` can solve your problem? [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS6c678f7b363d5da52e8f1ca1124a0430dcf-8000.html) is documentation about it and [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/popupmanager/) are a lot of useful samples.